# Azure Data Factory Private Endpoint Use Case

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-virtual-network, vnet, azure-private-link, azure-private-dns

I have all resources like SQL,ADLSv2,KeyVault, etc. with 'Selected Networks' access and private endpoints. My Azure Data Factory has no private endpoint, but its self-hosted integration runtime (SHIR) is in my vNet in which all other resources (like SQL,ADLS) are present. All linked services from ADF to other resources are 'Test connection=Successful'.

My aim is to make my azure environment secure with non-public access. Will I need a private endpoint on my Data Factory? If yes, why it's necessary, because all linked services are anyways passing. Please give your inputs why (or under which circumstances) ADF/portal private endpoint is necessary?

Microsoft Documentation for ADF private endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-private-link

[image: Microsoft Documentation for ADF private endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-private-link]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This involves certain use cases where you call the Data Factory end point.
Eg:

1. Communication from Integration Run time to Data Factory
2. In case you are triggering & Monitoring the pipeline via program (REST, Python, .net) you would access it via the private end point and not the default DNS of Data factory